# Ubuntu 12.04 running rake task in rails give error: cannot load such file -- Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, ubuntu-12.04

We are deploying a Rails application on a server running ubuntu 12.04.
We can start the server. But we don't have done any migrations. So we want to run `rake db:migrate` and we have this error: `cannot load such file -- Nokogiri`

Here the full trace:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- Nokogiri
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/www/collaide/lib/tasks/migrate_data.rake:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/www/collaide/lib/tasks/migrate_data.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `block in load_tasks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `each'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/www/collaide/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

The gem nokogiri is installed: running `gem list | grep nokogiri` give: nokogiri (1.6.1, 1.6.0) and at the good place: running `ls -l ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/ | grep nokogiri` give:

- drwxrwxr-x  8 *** *** 4096 déc.  20 20:39 nokogiri-1.6.0
- drwxrwxr-x  8 *** *** 4096 déc.  20 20:49 nokogiri-1.6.1

which is right.

nokogiri is only a dependency but we have added to the Gemfile, too.

And more crazy, in irb, `require 'nokogiri'` works

We need help, please. We are completely lost!

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: is it in your GEMFILE?

Comment: have you bundle installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for a typo (uppercase **N**):

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > require 'nokogiri'
=> true 

1.9.3-p392 :001 > require 'Nokogiri'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- Nokogiri
```